# Django. how to get a host name for db

Tags: django, django-views, host

I'm trying to connect to database:
in localhost I can do something like this:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user="root", passwd="", db="schooldb")
```

but in the server I want `'127.0.0.1'` to be a variable,
unfortunately

```
   h = request.get_host()
   return HttpResponse(h)
```

gives me `127.0.0.1:8000` 
So my question is how to truncate port and leave only `127.0.0.1`. Or may be you can suggest something better.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[request.get_host()][1]` gives you the server information for the request and not the database server information.

To get database information (assuming you have only one database named *default*), you can do:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST']
>>> 'MyDBServer'
>>> settings.DATABASES['default']['PORT']    
>>> '9999'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to have different environments for local and server purpose?

If yes and you are using django I think that the easiest way is to use [django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/) system and setup database hostname there.

On the server you can have other file with different settings and start server with that module. For example using manage.py tool with --settings flag.

```
./manage.py runserver --settings=project.settings_production
```

Edit: Remeber that development server is not for use on production environment.

By the way, `request.get_host()` [returns a remote hoste name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host).